# Unity yield WaitForSeconds() not working

Tags: unity, timer

I am new to Unity development. I started learning Unity by reading tutorials, demos, examples, and watching videos. And I am having some trouble with using this timer. Here is my code:

```
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision colli){

    if (colli.collider.name == "Car") {
        Debug.Log("On Collision naz ~.~");
        Destroy(Car);    
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        GameObject clone = (GameObject) Instantiate(Bum, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        StartCoroutine(deleteObject(clone));
        // Just want to delete "clone" object after 1 second
    }
}
    IEnumerator deleteObject(GameObject bum){
        Debug.Log("chuan bi destroy naz ~.~"); // <-- run normally
        yield return new  WaitForSeconds(1.0F);
        Debug.Log("Destroy rui naz =,='");    //  <-- not display
        Destroy (bum);
    }
```

Why won't this object be destroyed after 1 second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're going Destroy(this.gameObject) before starting the coroutine. A destroyed object cannot keep running a coroutine.

A solution would be to run the coroutine on the clone object.

Comment: work like charm, thank you and wish you have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

You're destroying the object that contains the coroutine.

A simple fix for this situation is to use the extended version of [`Destroy`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html).

```
// Destroy the bum after 1 second
   Destroy (bum, 1);
```